# python tkinter accepting user input through function

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, attributes

1) I receive an Attribute Error for [myText_Box](https://github.com/phillipsk/dictionary_Merriam-Webster_API/blob/master/py2dict.py#L145)

2) My goal is to accept user input through a text box and then define the word through an API definition method.

3) I am about to utilize this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685020/python-tkinter-prompt) to ask for a string -- How cold I resolve the attribute error? Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833449/tkinter-listbox-get-attribute-error) I was attemtping something along the lines of `calc.myText_Box`

```
calc = tk.Tk()
calc.title("VocabU")

Question_1 = str("Define which word?")
FRONT_PAGE = ['Define me!', Question_1]

def retrieve_input():
    input = calc.myText_Box.get("1.0",'end-1c')
    define_me = dictionary.get_definition(input)
    return define_me

USER_INP = retrieve_input()

#RESPONSE = str(dictionary.get_definition(input))
# set up GUI
row = 1
col = 0
for i in FRONT_PAGE:
    button_style = 'raised'
    #action =
    action = lambda x = retrieve_input(): click_event(x)
    tk.Button(calc, text = i, width = 17, height = 3, relief = button_style, command = action).grid(row = row, column = col, sticky = 'nesw')
    col += 1
    if col > 0: # if col > 4
        col = 0
        row += 1

display = tk.Entry(calc, width = 40, bg = "white", text = Question_1)
#display.pack
display.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 1) # columnspan = 5
```

Comment: Post the entire error.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined `myText_Box` anywhere in the code at https://github.com/phillipsk/dictionary_Merriam-Webster_API.

Attempting to reference it will raise an Attribute error, as will an attempt to access any undefined attribute on an object:

```
>>> a = object()
>>> a.myText_Box
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'myText_Box'
```

You need to create your Text widget and assign it to your `Tk()` instance, `calc`:

```
calc.myText_Box = Text(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

`input` is a reserved word in Python, try to use a different one!

Comment: `input` is _not_ a reserved word in Python. It is a built-in function. It is poor style to reassign it, but it is not illegal, and is not the cause of the OP's problem.